# It keeps saying ValueError: math domain error

Tags: python

I'm doing a math project in my computer science class and I need help fixing my code... It's quadratic formula

```
import math

play = 0

print("ax**2 + bx + c = 0")

while play==0:

    a = float(input("Enter A: "))

    b = float(input("Enter B: "))

    c = float(input("Enter C: "))

    d = (b**2) - (4*a*c)

solution1 = (-b - math.sqrt (d))/(2*a)
solution2 = (-b + math.sqrt (d))/(2*a)

print("The X value's are", solution1 ,solution2)
break
```

I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: you are probably trying to take the `sqrt` of a negative number, make sure your input is valid

Comment: Exactly, there's no error if `d` is positive.

Comment: what would I change in it?

Comment: you could either add a check `if d<0: break`  or throw an error or make sure your input is correct

Answer (score 2):

You are not validating against a situation where quadratic equation has no solution. Look at the example input:

```
gonczor@wiktor-papu:~/tmp$ python3 mymath.py 
ax**2 + bx + c = 0
Enter A: 1
Enter B: 2
Enter C: 1
The X value's are -1.0 -1.0
gonczor@wiktor-papu:~/tmp$ python3 mymath.py 
ax**2 + bx + c = 0
Enter A: 1
Enter B: 5
Enter C: 7
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mymath.py", line 17, in <module>
    solution1 = (-b - math.sqrt (d))/(2*a)
ValueError: math domain error
```

You you are trying to make a square root out of a negative number.

Comment: And print that quadratic equation has no solution (in real number space) it will do the trick ;)